# Mega-simple facebook status update

Tags: facebook, status

I found this recently:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?&message=Hello

Which does a very simple URL-based Facebook wall post.  I wondered if there's a similar thing for status updates?

Otherwise, what's the simplest way to set a facebook status update from a website?  Is there a Javascript plug-in that will do this, or do I definitely need to get right down into the API on the server-side?  The website this needs to integrate into is a legacy classic ASP site.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JS SDK.
Links for your reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Comment: Thanks. Looking into this further I believe there's actually no difference betweeen a status update and a wall post in this instance.  I also found that the link I posted above was legacy functionality which is depricated.  I found this http://ingig.net/weblog/2010/04/21/using-graph-api-to-post-status-update-with-c/ which is a simple C# implementation of a status update, which uses the proper API and isn't too scary :)